# Best way to paint rectangles in three.js

Tags: three.js

**EDIT: I solved my problem and [this](https://blipboard.io) is what is was for. It now uses raw webgl and two triangles for each rectangle.**

I'm a seasoned developer, but know next to nothing about 3d development.

I need to animate a million small rectangles where I set the coordinates in Javascript (rather than through a shader). (EDIT: It's a 2D job and I'm looking at webgl for performance reasons only.) I tweaked an existing threejs sample that uses "Points" to modify the coordinates in a `BufferGeometry` via Javascript and that performs really well, even with a million points.

The three.js concept of "Points", however, is a bit weird in that it appears they have to be squares - my rectangles can't be quite squares though, and they are of slightly different dimensions each.

I can think of a couple of workarounds, such as having foreground-colored squares partially overlap with squares of a background-color, thereby molding them into the correct rectangle. That's quite hacky though.

Another possibility would be to not do it with points but rather with proper triangles; but then I need to set 12 values from Javascript (2 triangles, 3 edges, 2 dimensions) rather than just the needed 4 (x, y, width, height). I suppose that could be improved with a vertex shader somehow, but that will be tricky for a noob like me.

I'm looking for some suggestions or, alternatively, a sample on how to set a large number of vertex coordinates from Javascript in threejs (the existing samples all appear to assume that manipulation is done in shaders, but that doesn't work so well for my use case).

EDIT - Here's a picture of how the rectangles could be laid out:

[image]

The rectangle's top and bottom edges are arbitrary, but they are organized into columns of arbitrary widths.

The rectangles of each column all have the same, uniform color.

Comment: Any explanatory pics of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @prisoner849 I added an image.

Comment: I didn't get: do you want to use a plane and paint rectangles on it, or you want to use particles?

Comment: @prisoner849 Is this question a "how" rather than a "what" and as such what I'm asking in the first place?

Comment: You can use `.map` property of a material, apply `canvas` to it, and draw rectangles on this canvas.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're trying to do. Your image looks like you might as well just be drawing an array of pixels. What is the point of using points if you're just going to display them in a grid right next to each other? A million points is basically the entire display if put in a grid. 1920x1080 is only 2 million pixels. Otherwise you can make points different shapes by applying at texture. https://threejs.org/examples/?q=points#webgl_points_billboards

Answer (score 1):

Just an option with `canvas` and `.map`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var gh = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10, "black", "black");
gh.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.5;
gh.position.z = 0.01;
scene.add(gh);

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var map = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 512;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function drawRectangle(x, y, width, height, color) {
  let xUnit = canvas.width / 10;
  let yUnit = canvas.height / 10;

  let x_ = x * xUnit;
  let y_ = y * yUnit;
  let w_ = width * xUnit;
  let h_ = height * yUnit;

  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x_, y_, w_, h_);
  map.needsUpdate = true;
}

drawRectangle(1, 1, 4, 3, "aqua");
drawRectangle(0, 6, 6, 3, "magenta");
drawRectangle(3, 2, 6, 6, "yellow");

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "white",
  map: map
}));
scene.add(plane);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Misunderstanding: What you're suggesting here doing it with a canvas (not webgl) and then showing how to use that in webgl. If that was performant enough I wouldn't be looking at webgl to begin with, but unfortunately it isn't - I've already tried various 2d html technologies and they are all insufficient when the object count is really high.

Comment: @John What do you want to use it for? What's the final goal/result?

Comment: It's for a new kind of real-time event display that uses a logarithmic timescale. It kind of looks as if I have to use proper meshes to make this work, so I'll likely have to learn threejs in a bit more depth.

Comment: I added a link to my result in the question now, thinking you might deserve a better explanation given the effort you put in to my mysterious question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the source for these samples:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=buffer#webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=buffer#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=buffer#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing_billboards

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=buffer#webgl_buffergeometry_points